# Styled components, toggle state with mapped buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, styled-components

I have 4 buttons that are generated through my map function. When I click the button I would like the style to be applied to only that 1 button. Right now the style is being applied to all buttons.

Where am I going wrong?

```
const MultiChoiceQuestions = props => {
  const { multiChoiceArray, handleClick, inputValue, updateInputValue } = props
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  console.log('state', active)
  // () => handleClick(questionChoice)
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        return (
          <Button
            active={active}
            type="button"
            key={questionChoice.id}
            onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
          >
            {questionChoice.text}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </ButtonContainer>
  )
}

const Button = styled.button`
  height: 3rem;
  width: 20rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #c7c7c76b;
  background-color: ${props => (props.active ? 'green' : 'white')};
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
  font-weight: 400;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #ff00006b;
    transform: scale(1.25);
    font-weight: 800;
    border: none;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the active button's ID in the state. And when rendering buttons, check if the button’s ID is equal to the active ID state. It will be an analogue of radio buttons.

```
const MultiChoiceQuestions = props => {
  const { multiChoiceArray, handleClick, inputValue, updateInputValue } = props
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState()
  console.log('state', active)
  // () => handleClick(questionChoice)
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        return (
          <Button
            active={questionChoice.id === activeId}
            type="button"
            key={questionChoice.id}
            onClick={() => setActive(questionChoice.id)}
          >
            {questionChoice.text}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </ButtonContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) Will accept as an answer when I can

Answer (score 0):

You have only one `state` variable for all the buttons. You can either create a new button component (with its own state) or create an array with four states.